# knex times out when reading tables that are huge

Tags: node.js, azure-sql-database, knex.js

I'm having a huge table in Azure SQL database which has about 1000+ rows. I'm building a SQL backend using NodeJS and Knex. Every time I try to fetch the contents of the entire table, the connection times out. However when I try to query the contents using a filter, everything works fine. My code looks something like below. Do I have to handle queries that return large amounts of data differently?

```
activity: {
    get: async (queryObject) => {
      
      return queryObject != null
        ? knex('Activities').where(queryObject)
        : knex('Activities');
    },
```

Comment: Take a look the .stream() (http://knexjs.org/#Streams-stream ) method. If dialect/driver supports it (e.g. Postgres) rows are read progressively.

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1152.

Comment: Using paging and multiple queries might be more robust that using knex's streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I summarize the solution as below.

If you want to quest large rows in one table with `knex`, I suggest you use `knex.Streams.stream()` method to read data. For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1152).

For example

```
const options = {
    client: '',
    connection: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        user: 'user12',
        password: 's$cret',
        database: 'mydb'
    }
}
const knex = require('knex')(options);
const stream=  knex.select("*").from("CSVTest").stream()
 stream.on('error', function (err) {
                        // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
                    })
                        .on('fields', function (fields) {
                            // the field packets for the rows to follow
                        })
                        .on('result', function (row) {
                            // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O

                            processRow(row);
                        })
                        .on('end', function () {
                            // all rows have been received
                        });
```

Comment: This works but I'm implementing this logic for an API. How do I stream it to the response object when replying back to the client?

Comment: @PerumalPerumal I think you return your response in `end` action.